# Store the result of mysql query in some file

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I want to store the result of MySQL `select` query in some file text from aliquibase script. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from table
INTO OUTFILE 'c:\temp\2016.csv' 
fields TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';